# Verificar certificado X509Certificate2

Tags: c#

existe alguma maneira de eu verificar se o certificado A3 esta conectado ao computador? Algum tipo de validação por exemplo. Trabalho com uma aplicação que faz uso de certificado A3, porém não faço esta validação de se o certificado esta conectado ou não, alguém conhece alguma maneira de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Busca Certificado
var certificado = new X509Certificate2(caminhoCertificado);

//Instancia o registro de certificados na maquina local
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

//Abre em modo de leitura
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);


var certificados = store.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, //Criterio de busca
    certificado.SubjectName, //Valor para busca
    false);//Os inválidos também

if (certificados != null && certificados.Count > 0)
{
   //Certificado Já instalado
}
```